# If I enter the letters TL in cell A8, is there a way to turn that cell and multiple others in that row blue?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

If I enter the letters TL in cell A8, is there a way to turn that cell and multiple others in that row blue? Is there a way to have multiple letter/color variations?

I have 8 two letter combinations that correspond to 8 colors. For example:
TS=light blue  TC=medium blue  TL=dark blue     DD=black 
RS=light green  RC=medium green  RL=dark green  LT=brown
I'd like to enter one of these these letter combinations into M8 & have columns, B,C,E,F,K-AM in row 8 turn the corresponding color. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Just row 8 or others?

Comment: Just simply use 8 conditional formatting rules on those columns looking for the value in `M8`.

Comment: You can use conditional formatting to get the result: https://www.vertex42.com/blog/excel-tips/how-to-use-conditional-formatting-in-excel.html

Answer (score 1):

> If I enter the letters TL in cell **A8** ... enter one of these these letter combinations into **M8** & have columns, B,C,E,F,K-AM in row 8 ...

Your narrative is confusing. This code is for M8.

Adjust the worksheet name and the RGB parameters for the colours you want then run this code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub addCFRs()

    Dim i As Long, rng As Range, arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant

    arr1 = Array("TS", "TC", "TL", "DD", "RS", "RC", "RL", "LT")
    arr2 = Array(RGB(0, 0, 255), RGB(0, 0, 128), RGB(0, 0, 64), RGB(0, 0, 0), _
                 RGB(0, 255, 0), RGB(0, 128, 0), RGB(0, 64, 0), RGB(0, 0, 0))

    With Worksheets("sheet6")

        Set rng = Intersect(.Range("B:C, E:F, K:AM"), .Range("8:8"))

        With rng

            .FormatConditions.Delete

            For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)

                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$M8=" & Chr(34) & arr1(i) & Chr(34)
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = arr2(i)

            Next i

        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Most of the RGBs are somewhat close to what you want except for brown; I have no idea what RGB makes up brown.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using conditional formatting.
You will need a separate formula for each colour.

- Highlight the cells you wish to change colour in row 8 (you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click to select separate cells)
- Go to "Conditional Formatting" and select "New rule"
- Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
- In the rule description type `=$M8="TL"`
- Click on "Format" and choose the "Fill" tab at the top
- Select the correct colour for the code
- Click OK and then OK again.
  All done for row 8.

If you want it to do more rows, go to "Conditional Formatting" and select "Manage rules".

Select the icon to the right of the "Applies to" box and then highlight all the areas that you want to change colour. Again, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to select separate areas. You can select entire columns if you want but this can slow the sheet down.

Once you have this set up you can repeat the process for the other colour codes, just replace `TL` in the formula with the code you wish to use.